# Is it possible to create a filter (block some elements) over a embedded object element?

Tags: css, html, object

I want to create a little HTML game where you have to use an "inApp" Browser. Via this code

```html
<object data="https://de.wikipedia.org" width="600" height="400"> <embed src="https://de.wikipedia.org" width="600" height="400"> </embed> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>
```

But there are some things the user shouldn't access on the site, like the search bar.

However, is it possible to create a filter like code, that blocks these elements?

Thanks in advance

Nico

Comment: If target pages are external to your domain no.

Comment: It is not possible if the targeted site is different from your domain.

Comment: allright, and what if I make a addon like plugin within my application, so just like adblocks.